# "Illegal case" when using special symbols in case in c++

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

I have some problem, when I use special char case in c++. I try use '{' but it's over with error to.
Visual Studio 2010.
Here is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
{
    switch(inputString[i])
        case '{':
            nowChar = inputString[i];
            nowCaret = i;
            break;
        case '[':
            nowChar = inputString[i];
            nowCaret = i;
            break;
        case '(':
            nowChar = inputString[i];
            nowCaret = i;
            break;
}
```

How I can remove these errors? I really don't have any idea about it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open and end your switch with braces.

```
switch() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have just forgot the brace for the switch statement. Btw, it will be better to have `default` in a switch statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
{
    switch(inputString[i]) {
    case '{':
        nowChar = inputString[i];
        nowCaret = i;
        break;
    case '[':
        nowChar = inputString[i];
        nowCaret = i;
        break;
    case '(':
        nowChar = inputString[i];
        nowCaret = i;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `{` and `}` around the cases:

```
switch(inputString[i])
{ //<------------------------------  this
    case '{':
        nowChar = inputString[i];
        nowCaret = i;
        break;
    case '[':
        nowChar = inputString[i];
        nowCaret = i;
        break;
    case '(':
        nowChar = inputString[i];
        nowCaret = i;
        break;
} //<------------------------------- and this
```

A `switch` block starts with `{` when it has **multiple** cases. If it has just one `case`, then `{` and `}` are not mandatory.

```
switch(i)
     case 0 : 
           // code 
          break;
```

Here `{` and `}` are not mandatory.

Comment: Oh, I really nedd more sleep. Thx!